# Problem to implement socket handler Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, sockets, client

I am trying to implement multiplayer scrabble and to handle socket (client side). I implemented a module but II dont know how to resolve this issue :

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

export module SocketHandler {

  let activeSocket: SocketIOClient.Socket;

  export function requestSocket(server: string): any {

    if (activeSocket === undefined) {
        activeSocket = io.connect(server);
    }
    return activeSocket;
  }

  export function disconnectSocket(): void {
    activeSocket.disconnect();
    activeSocket = undefined;
  }

}
```

Error: export 'connect' (imported as 'io') was not found in 'socket.io-client' (possible exports: Manager, Socket, default, io)
error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'SocketIOClient'.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the prefix `io` before everything because you imported it with this name. [Use directly `io` to connect](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/).

```
activeSocket: io.Socket;

requestSocket(server: string): any {
  if (this.activeSocket === undefined) {
      this.activeSocket = io.io(server);
  }
  return this.activeSocket;
}

disconnectSocket(): void {
  this.activeSocket.disconnect();
  this.activeSocket = undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try use :

```
import * as socketIO from 'socket.io'
```

Comment: i have tried but dosent work, this modul is critical for my project so please if you can help me, i get those errors:
Error: src/app/modules/socketHandler.module.ts:1:1 - error TS6133: 'socketIO' is declared but its value is never read.
1 import * as socketIO from 'socket.io';
Error: src/app/modules/socketHandler.module.ts:4:23 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'SocketIO' as a type.
4     let activeSocket: SocketIO
Error: src/app/modules/socketHandler.module.ts:9:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'io'.
9             activeSocket = io.connect(server);